# Solving the recurrence relation $a_n=p(1-a_{n-1})+(1-p)a_{n-1}$?

Tags: probability, recurrence-relations

I am attempting to solve a recurrence relation which stems from calculating the probability that there are an even number of heads after $n$ tosses of a biased coin with $P(\text{heads})=p$. I managed to obtain

$$a_n=p(1-a_{n-1})+(1-p)a_{n-1}.$$

I attempted to solve it using the generic method of “converting subscript to exponent” which I found in this MSE post. This gives me the polynomial

$$a^n=p+(1-2p)a^{n-1}.$$

I am now stuck with this equation. I’ve considered using the factor theorem, but to no avail so far. Could someone help me with this part? Thank you!

Comment: Hint: Use the change of variable $$b_n=a_n-\frac12$$

Comment: @Did hi, where does this hint come from/what property of the equation shows us that this substitution is best?

Comment: This is an affine transform $a_{n+1}=Aa_n+B$. For every $A\ne1$, each affine transform is conjugate to the linear transform $b_{n+1}=Ab_n$, where $b_n$ is simply $a_n$ centered around the fixed point $x^*$ of the affine transformation $f(x)=Ax+B$. Here $A=1-2p$ and $x^*=\frac12$ hence $b_n=a_n-\frac12$ works for every $p\ne0$ (and the case $p=0$ is direct anyway).

Comment: Make the Substitution $$a_n=q^n$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner No. Please try to avoid polluting this thread.

Answer (score 1):

$$q = 1 - 2p$$
$$a_n = p + q a_{n-1}$$
$$a_n = p + pq + pq^2 + \dots q^n a_0 $$
$$a_n = p \left( \frac{q^n - 1}{q-1} + q^n a_0 \right) $$